# Como evitar que imprima caracteres basura

Tags: c++, c

Hola buenas tardes a todos, hace rato estoy intentando hacer un struct que permita poner hasta 50 peliculas, no más, pero a la hora de imprimir las peliculas que ingresé en pantalla me arroja carácteres basura que no sé como quitar ¿Cómo hago para indicarle que quiero mostrar solamente las peliculas que ingresé y no símbolos extraños?
Estoy aprendiendo así que tal vez tenga bastantes errores mi código.

```
struct peliculas {

char titulo[tamPer];
char actores[tamPer];
char director[tamPer];
char genero[tamPer];
int duracion;
int anioRealiz;
char estreno[tamPer];
int diasFilm; };

void cargar(peliculas pelis[cant]) {

int i=0;
char opcion;

while((opcion!='n') && (i<cant)) {
    system("CLS");
    fflush(stdin);
    printf(" A partir de ahora ud esta agregando %i peliculas. \n\n\n",i+1);
    printf(" Ingrese el titulo de la pelicula:\n");
    gets(pelis[i].titulo);
    printf(" Ingrese cantidad de actores principales:\n (ej, Fer, Jesus, etc)\n");
    gets(pelis[i].actores);
    printf(" Ingrese el nombre del director:");
    gets(pelis[i].director);
    printf(" Ingrese el genero ej: drama/comedia/etc:\n");
    gets(pelis[i].genero);
    printf(" Ingrese la duracion expresado en minutos ej;\n 1,5 (hora y media):\n");
    scanf("%i",&pelis[i].duracion);
    printf(" Ingrese el año de realizacion:\n");
    scanf("%i",&pelis[i].anioRealiz);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf(" Ingrese la fecha de estreno: \n");
    scanf("%s",pelis[i].estreno);
    printf(" Ingrese la cantidad de dias de filmacion:\n");
    scanf("%i",&pelis[i].diasFilm);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf(" Desea seguir agregando peliculas?\n (s/n) para continuar: ");
    scanf("%c",&opcion);
    i++;
}}
void listaGeneral(peliculas pelis[cant]) {

for(int i=0; i<cant; i++) {
    puts(pelis[i].titulo);
    puts(pelis[i].actores);
    puts(pelis[i].director);
    puts(pelis[i].genero);
    printf("%i",pelis[i].duracion);
    printf("%i",pelis[i].anioRealiz);
    printf("%s",pelis[i].estreno);
    printf("%i",pelis[i].diasFilm);
    printf("\n\n\n");
}   }
```

Comment: cant está definido con 50 elementos y con la misma cantidad, pelis[cant], no sé si tenga algo que ver.

Comment: Tienes que guardar en algún lugar el número de películas ingresadas (que es el valor de `i` al salir del bucle `while`). Por ejemplo puedes hacer que `cargar()` retorne ese valor. La función pricipal lo recogerá en una variable y deberá  pasarle ese valor como parámetro a `listaGeneral()`. Digamos que llamas a ese parámetro `num_pelis`. Entonces el bucle que imprime irá hasta `i<num_pelis` en vez de `cant`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder! Suena más complicado de lo que pensé, voy a tratar de hacerlo :D

Comment: ¿Cuál es el lenguaje? ¿[tag:c] o [tag:c++]? La respuesta es muy diferente en cada uno de los lenguajes.

Comment: Es lenguaje C, aún no he podido solucionarlo;(

Answer (score 0):

Puedes declarar una variable global en este caso **int num_pelis;** y vas a incrementarlo cada que agregues una pelicula a tu arreglo de structs y en la condicion de tu ciclo for para imprimir las peliculas quedaria asi **i<num_pelis** asi evitaras que tu ciclo for recorra todo tu arreglo de struct e imprima valores basura.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).